# MVUE of Bernoulli r.v. when $p\in [1/2,1)$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

> $X_1, X_2\dots , X_n$ are independent Bernoulli r.v. s.t. $P(X_i=1)=p$, $i=1,2,\dots , n$, where $p\in [1/2,1)$.
>
> (a) Is $T=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ MVUE of $p$? Justify it.

It can be easily shown that $T$ is MVUE if $p\in (0,1)$, since $T$ is complete sufficient statistics(as belongs to exponential family) and unbiased estimator by Lehmann-Scheffe theorem. But here $p\in(1/2,1]$. I don't think the result would be same(or may be same). I am confused!!

What I did is that:

Let $T^*=a\space \text{if $T<.5$ and}\\ \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space bT\space \text{if $T\geq.5$}$

$a,b$ are such that $T^*$ is u.e. of $p.$

Then I tried to find $a,b$ such that $Var(T^*)<Var(T)$. But I don't think this is right.

Comment: I think the point of the question may be to illustrate that the minimum variance estimator may not be unbiased

Comment: @Henry so you are saying that $T$ is not MVUE since $T$ is not u.e.?

Comment: think of the situation where $T \lt 0.5$. because of the prior $p \in [\frac12,1]$ the best estimate is $p=0.5$,

Comment: @DavidHolden I did that in exam, and concluded that $T$ can not be MVUE, and tried to show that their must be another $T^*$ which is u.e., but failed to show $T^*$ is MVUE.

Comment: No - I am saying that $T_0$ will be biased though with a lower variance.  What makes you think $T$ would become biased?

Comment: okk, @Henry I was saying we can make another u.e. $T^*$, using $T$, which is u.e. and var$(T^*)<$var$(T)$

Comment: My whole point to ask this question is if $T$ is MVUE  of$p$ or not!

Comment: I can not understand: did statistics $T$ cease to be sufficient and complete? Why we think that it is not MVUE?